# Making web app with Restful API

Tags: node.js, rest, express, web

I'm making web app using node.js express with Restful API.

And, to use my web app, the user must login. If user doesn't login, he always stays in login page.

But, I heard that restful api doesn't use session or cookie information to maintain user login.

So, I heard that it use JWT. So, I want to use this. But, I saw that it has to compare token information when user access Restful API.

Then, in my case, should the user always have to request token information to the web app server to use my web service? (I mean add token in request header when user request every page)

Comment: Just… use a session cookie.

Comment: But, I heard that session is not accepted to restful service

Comment: That's not correct and it doesn't matter if it’s the most convenient way for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> HTML Local Storage

When you get JWT token save some value at local storage `localStorage.setItem("logenin", "yes");`
and check at every page or where you need this infomation `localStorage.getItem("logenin");`

Comment: or you can use `sessionStorage`